# Clientside react-script overrides serverside rendered props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

In my serverside react rendering, I pass a property to the JSX:

```
markup: React.renderToString(Admin({ field1: "Hallo" }))
```

The JSX looks like this:

```
 <MaterialTextField hintText="field1" floatingLabelText="field1" type="text" name="field1" value={this.props.field1} />
```

Now, I ned to render the JSX also on clientside for having the event listeners, etc.:

```
React.render(
    <Admin />,
    document.getElementById('react-app')
);
```

The problem is: Because the rendered markups are not the same, the value of the text-field gets lost. How could I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React will check that any initial markup present matches what's produced for the first render on the client by comparing checksums between the initial client render and a checksum attribute in the server-rendered markup, so you *must* make the same props available for the initial render on the client in order to reuse the markup.

A common way to do this is to serialise the props to JSON so they can easily be included as a variable in the initial HTML sent to the client:

```
res.render('react.jade', {
  markup: React.renderToString(React.createElement(MyComponent, props)),
  props: JSON.stringify(props)
})
```

...

```
body
  div#app
    != markup
  script window.INITIAL_PROPS = !{props}
  script(src='/js/app.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

By passing it as prop to the Admin component just as you pass `this.props.field1` to the MaterialTextfield using `<Admin field1="Hallo" />`

Comment: But I don't want to pass it as a prop again in the JavaScript. Imo this would be very bad, because I have to get the value of the prop in the Node.js and the JavaScript-Code.

Comment: If you want to reuse the initial markup from the server, you *have to* pass the same props.